# Exception when opening Parse push notification

Tags: android, push-notification, parse-platform

I setup [Parse push Android SDK 1.7.0](https://parse.com/docs/android_guide) and can receive pushes without any problem. However, when opening the push notification my app crashes with the following exception:

> android.content.ActivityNotFoundException: No Activity found to handle
>   Intent { act=android.intent.action.VIEW dat= flg=0x1000c000 (has
>   extras) }

I also tried subclassing [`ParsePushBroadcastReceiver`](http://parse.com/docs/android/api/com/parse/ParsePushBroadcastReceiver.html) with `getActivity()` always returning the main activity class, same result. Below is the full stacktrace:

```
E/AndroidRuntime﹕ FATAL EXCEPTION: main
Process: com.ers.test, PID: 13513
java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start receiver com.ers.test.MyPushBroadcastReceiver: android.content.ActivityNotFoundException: No Activity found to handle Intent { act=android.intent.action.VIEW dat= flg=0x1000c000 (has extras) }
        at android.app.ActivityThread.handleReceiver(ActivityThread.java:2452)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.access$1700(ActivityThread.java:144)
        at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1281)
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:136)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5146)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:796)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:612)
        at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
 Caused by: android.content.ActivityNotFoundException: No Activity found to handle Intent { act=android.intent.action.VIEW dat= flg=0x1000c000 (has extras) }
        at android.app.Instrumentation.checkStartActivityResult(Instrumentation.java:1632)
        at android.app.Instrumentation.execStartActivitiesAsUser(Instrumentation.java:1481)
        at android.app.ContextImpl.startActivitiesAsUser(ContextImpl.java:1136)
        at android.content.ContextWrapper.startActivitiesAsUser(ContextWrapper.java:344)
        at android.content.ContextWrapper.startActivitiesAsUser(ContextWrapper.java:344)
        at android.app.TaskStackBuilder.startActivities(TaskStackBuilder.java:221)
        at android.app.TaskStackBuilder.startActivities(TaskStackBuilder.java:232)
        at android.app.TaskStackBuilder.startActivities(TaskStackBuilder.java:208)
        at com.parse.TaskStackBuilderHelper.startActivities(TaskStackBuilderHelper.java:19)
        at com.parse.ParsePushBroadcastReceiver.onPushOpen(ParsePushBroadcastReceiver.java:202)
        at com.parse.ParsePushBroadcastReceiver.onReceive(ParsePushBroadcastReceiver.java:108)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.handleReceiver(ActivityThread.java:2445)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.access$1700(ActivityThread.java:144)
        at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1281)
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:136)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5146)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:796)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:612)
        at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

Comment: Adding `<action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW" />` to desired activity doesn't help.

Answer (score 102, accepted):

After spending few hours. Found a solution:
Implement your receiver and extends ParsePushBroadcastReceiver class.

Receiver.java

```
public class Receiver extends ParsePushBroadcastReceiver {

    @Override
    public void onPushOpen(Context context, Intent intent) {
        Log.e("Push", "Clicked");
        Intent i = new Intent(context, HomeActivity.class);
        i.putExtras(intent.getExtras());
        i.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
        context.startActivity(i);
    }
}
```

Use it in manifest, (Instead of using ParsePushBroadcastReceiver)

Code for project's manifest:

```
<receiver
            android:name="your.package.name.Receiver"
            android:exported="false" >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="com.parse.push.intent.RECEIVE" />
                <action android:name="com.parse.push.intent.DELETE" />
                <action android:name="com.parse.push.intent.OPEN" />
            </intent-filter>
        </receiver>
```

Happy Coding!!

Comment: This works! However having to create the intent myself means I am losing all the data in the extra (com.parse.Data and com.parse.Channel), will have to copy those over. Waiting to see if this is improved in the next sdk release.

Comment: Was using 1.5 before this and everything worked fine. Updated to 1.7 and the problem seems to occur

Comment: Thnx mate! The new Parse push tutorial gave barely no hints how to bind an Activity to the handler.

Comment: This answer worked great using Parse 1.7.1 w/Android Studio.  Thanks!

Comment: @KrisKrause and Ahmad I am using android suited and 1.7.1 should this line be removed `PushService.setDefaultPushCallback(this, MainActivity.class);` From MyApplication.java, when I do I can no longer recover push notifications? But is depreciated so I don't know why it should be kept?

Comment: @SongQian did you keep this line `PushService.setDefaultPushCallback(this, MainActivity.class);` or did u remove it see comment above

Comment: And you saved my "few hours" from yours. Def +1 as the quick start parse guide is amazinglt silent on this.

Comment: @iqueqiorio I removed it.

Comment: @iqueqiorio: Just remove PushService.setDefaultPushCallback(this, MainActivity.class); don't need this function in v1.7.1

Comment: Note: By using this solution, you lose the ability for Parse to automatically handle the [uri part of customized notification](https://parse.com/docs/push_guide#options-data/Android). So, if you need/want to dynamically set the `Activity`, you should use the [other answer](https://parse.com/docs/push_guide#options-data/Android), which is basically the Parse source code with one line added.

Comment: @AhmadRaza : I have a problem with your code, my logic is like that, when I receive the push I need to play custom sound and make some logic in background, and then add notification to android, and when user click on the notification I open the application, every thing is fine but it doesn't report to parse that user open the notification, could you please help 
??

Comment: @AmiraElsayedIsmail: When you click on notification, it must be opening any activity from your application. Just put this line ParseAnalytics.trackAppOpened(getIntent()); in that activity's oncreate(). by that line, Parse will track the opening.

Comment: @Ahmad Raza, I implemented your suggestion. but still I am getting error as when I tap on received notification it first display "Unfortunately App has stopped" error message popup and then going to open my app. I tested it on emulator first and then actual android device same problem for both. Here is logcat : http://pastebin.com/iPDnTiZp.

Comment: @Mohini: Check your profitpips.MainActivity. It is throwing illigalStateException. May be that is causing null pointer issue. java.lang.IllegalStateException: ParsePlugins is already initialized

Answer (score 32):

The cause of this exception is when `ParsePushBroadcastReceiver` wants to open the empty uri in your push message in this code :

```
String uriString = null;
    try
    {
      JSONObject pushData = new JSONObject(intent.getStringExtra("com.parse.Data"));
      uriString = pushData.optString("uri");
    }
    catch (JSONException e)
    {
      Parse.logE("com.parse.ParsePushReceiver", "Unexpected JSONException when receiving push data: ", e);
    }
    if (uriString != null) {
          activityIntent = new Intent("android.intent.action.VIEW", Uri.parse(uriString));
        } else {
          activityIntent = new Intent(context, cls);
        }
```

If you just push a message, the `uriString` will be empty not null, So `context.startActivity(activityIntent);` will open an empty uri and exception occurs.

To solve this issue you can subclass `ParsePushBroadcastReceiver` (thanks to @Ahmad Raza) and override onPushopen like this :

```
public class Receiver extends ParsePushBroadcastReceiver {

    @Override
    protected void onPushOpen(Context context, Intent intent) {

        ParseAnalytics.trackAppOpenedInBackground(intent);

        String uriString = null;
        try {
            JSONObject pushData = new JSONObject(intent.getStringExtra("com.parse.Data"));
            uriString = pushData.optString("uri");
        } catch (JSONException e) {
            Log.v("com.parse.ParsePushReceiver", "Unexpected JSONException when receiving push data: ", e);
        }
        Class<? extends Activity> cls = getActivity(context, intent);
        Intent activityIntent;
        if (uriString != null && !uriString.isEmpty()) {
            activityIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, Uri.parse(uriString));
        } else {
            activityIntent = new Intent(context, MainActivity.class);
        }
        activityIntent.putExtras(intent.getExtras());
        if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= 16) {
            TaskStackBuilder stackBuilder = TaskStackBuilder.create(context);
            stackBuilder.addParentStack(cls);
            stackBuilder.addNextIntent(activityIntent);
            stackBuilder.startActivities();
        } else {
            activityIntent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
            activityIntent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);
            context.startActivity(activityIntent);
        }
    }
}
```

and update Manifest like this :

```
<receiver
            android:name="your.package.name.Receiver"
            android:exported="false" >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="com.parse.push.intent.RECEIVE" />
                <action android:name="com.parse.push.intent.DELETE" />
                <action android:name="com.parse.push.intent.OPEN" />
            </intent-filter>
        </receiver>
```

I hope they solve the problem in their next update.

Comment: Can I just say I have been trying to get this Parse Push to work for over two weeks. Tried everything and almost lost my mind!!! You sir @Virusman are a complete legend! I don't understand why it worked for me but it did! Thank you!!