# App crashes on test push notification using parse

Tags: java, android, xml, crash, parse-platform

As given in their quickstart guide for push notifications, I did everything. But whenever I try sending a test push, the app crashes. I have gone through all online help resources possible, but everything seems right except the execution.

My main-> Application.java

package-> com.virus.buzzkill;

```
public class BuzzKillApplication extends Application {

    @Override
    public void onCreate() {
          super.onCreate();
          Parse.initialize(this, "YhcMXhTCr65bWiI2RB4voL", "R7QWGNPMjIPh1CHTxZRXxuzgu");
          ParseInstallation.getCurrentInstallation().saveInBackground(); 

        }
}
```

My AndroidManifest.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.virus.buzzkill"
    android:versionCode="1"
    android:versionName="1.0" >

    <uses-sdk
        android:minSdkVersion="14"
        android:targetSdkVersion="19" />

    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WAKE_LOCK" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.VIBRATE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.RECEIVE_BOOT_COMPLETED" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.GET_ACCOUNTS" />
    <uses-permission android:name="com.google.android.c2dm.permission.RECEIVE" />


    <uses-feature
        android:name="android.hardware.camera"
        android:required="true" />



    <permission
        android:name="com.virus.buzzkill.permission.C2D_MESSAGE"
        android:protectionLevel="signature" />

    <uses-permission android:name="com.virus.buzzkill.permission.C2D_MESSAGE" />

    <application
        android:name=".BuzzKillApplication"
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >
        <activity
            android:name=".MainActivity"
            android:label="@string/app_name"
            android:screenOrientation="portrait" >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
        <activity
            android:name=".LoginActivity"
            android:label="@string/title_activity_login"
            android:screenOrientation="portrait" >
        </activity>
        <activity
            android:name=".SignUpActivity"
            android:label="@string/title_activity_sign_up"
            android:parentActivityName="com.virus..buzzkill.LoginActivity"
            android:screenOrientation="portrait" >
        </activity>
        <activity
            android:name=".EditFriendsActivity"
            android:label="@string/title_activity_edit_friends"
            android:parentActivityName=".MainActivity"
            android:screenOrientation="portrait" >
            <meta-data
                android:name="android.support.PARENT_ACTIVITY"
                android:value="com.virus.buzzkill.MainActivity" />
        </activity>
        <activity
            android:name=".RecipientsActivity"
            android:label="@string/title_activity_recipients"
            android:parentActivityName=".MainActivity"
            android:screenOrientation="portrait" >
            <meta-data
                android:name="android.support.PARENT_ACTIVITY"
                android:value="com.virus.buzzkill.MainActivity" />
        </activity>
        <activity
            android:name=".ViewImageActivity"
            android:label="@string/title_activity_view_image"
            android:parentActivityName=".MainActivity"
            android:screenOrientation="portrait" >
            <meta-data
                android:name="android.support.PARENT_ACTIVITY"
                android:value="com.virus.buzzkill.MainActivity" />
        </activity>

        <service android:name="com.parse.PushService" />

        <receiver android:name="com.parse.ParseBroadcastReceiver" >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.BOOT_COMPLETED" />
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.USER_PRESENT" />
            </intent-filter>
        </receiver>
        <receiver
            android:name="com.parse.ParsePushBroadcastReceiver"
            android:exported="false" >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="com.parse.push.intent.RECEIVE" />
                <action android:name="com.parse.push.intent.DELETE" />
                <action android:name="com.parse.push.intent.OPEN" />
            </intent-filter>
        </receiver>
        <receiver
            android:name="com.parse.GcmBroadcastReceiver"
            android:permission="com.google.android.c2dm.permission.SEND" >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="com.google.android.c2dm.intent.RECEIVE" />
                <action android:name="com.google.android.c2dm.intent.REGISTRATION" />

                <category android:name="com.virus.buzzkill" />
            </intent-filter>
        </receiver>
    </application>

</manifest>
```

The logcat detail

```
 10-04 20:02:08.544: W/ActivityThread(16322): Application com.virus.buzzkill can be debugged on port 8100...
    10-04 20:02:08.860: I/Adreno-EGL(16322): <qeglDrvAPI_eglInitialize:410>: EGL 1.4 QUALCOMM build: AU_LINUX_ANDROID_LNX.LA.3.5.1_RB1.04.04.02.048.018_msm8226_LNX.LA.3.5.1_RB1__release_AU ()
    10-04 20:02:08.860: I/Adreno-EGL(16322): OpenGL ES Shader Compiler Version: E031.24.00.08
    10-04 20:02:08.860: I/Adreno-EGL(16322): Build Date: 03/07/14 Fri
    10-04 20:02:08.860: I/Adreno-EGL(16322): Local Branch: 
    10-04 20:02:08.860: I/Adreno-EGL(16322): Remote Branch: quic/LNX.LA.3.5.1_RB1.1
    10-04 20:02:08.860: I/Adreno-EGL(16322): Local Patches: NONE
    10-04 20:02:08.860: I/Adreno-EGL(16322): Reconstruct Branch: AU_LINUX_ANDROID_LNX.LA.3.5.1_RB1.04.04.02.048.018 + f2fd134 +  NOTHING
    10-04 20:02:08.911: D/OpenGLRenderer(16322): Enabling debug mode 0
    10-04 20:02:08.991: D/dalvikvm(16322): GC_FOR_ALLOC freed 480K, 46% free 9407K/17184K, paused 16ms, total 16ms
    10-04 20:02:09.025: I/dalvikvm-heap(16322): Grow heap (frag case) to 23.393MB for 12767920-byte allocation
    10-04 20:02:34.759: I/Activity(16322): Pritish
    10-04 20:02:36.055: D/dalvikvm(16322): GC_FOR_ALLOC freed 1629K, 25% free 22282K/29656K, paused 21ms, total 21ms
    10-04 20:02:50.597: D/AndroidRuntime(16322): Shutting down VM
    10-04 20:02:50.597: W/dalvikvm(16322): threadid=1: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0x4169cd40)
    10-04 20:02:50.600: E/AndroidRuntime(16322): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
    10-04 20:02:50.600: E/AndroidRuntime(16322): Process: com.virus.buzzkill, PID: 16322
    10-04 20:02:50.600: E/AndroidRuntime(16322): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start receiver com.parse.ParsePushBroadcastReceiver: java.lang.NullPointerException
    10-04 20:02:50.600: E/AndroidRuntime(16322):    at android.app.ActivityThread.handleReceiver(ActivityThread.java:2441)
    10-04 20:02:50.600: E/AndroidRuntime(16322):    at android.app.ActivityThread.access$1700(ActivityThread.java:139)
    10-04 20:02:50.600: E/AndroidRuntime(16322):    at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1286)
    10-04 20:02:50.600: E/AndroidRuntime(16322):    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
    10-04 20:02:50.600: E/AndroidRuntime(16322):    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:136)
    10-04 20:02:50.600: E/AndroidRuntime(16322):    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5086)
    10-04 20:02:50.600: E/AndroidRuntime(16322):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
    10-04 20:02:50.600: E/AndroidRuntime(16322):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
    10-04 20:02:50.600: E/AndroidRuntime(16322):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:785)
    10-04 20:02:50.600: E/AndroidRuntime(16322):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:601)
    10-04 20:02:50.600: E/AndroidRuntime(16322):    at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
    10-04 20:02:50.600: E/AndroidRuntime(16322): Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
    10-04 20:02:50.600: E/AndroidRuntime(16322):    at com.parse.ParsePushBroadcastReceiver.getSmallIconId(ParsePushBroadcastReceiver.java:253)
    10-04 20:02:50.600: E/AndroidRuntime(16322):    at com.parse.ParsePushBroadcastReceiver.getNotification(ParsePushBroadcastReceiver.java:335)
    10-04 20:02:50.600: E/AndroidRuntime(16322):    at com.parse.ParsePushBroadcastReceiver.onPushReceive(ParsePushBroadcastReceiver.java:143)
    10-04 20:02:50.600: E/AndroidRuntime(16322):    at com.parse.ParsePushBroadcastReceiver.onReceive(ParsePushBroadcastReceiver.java:104)
    10-04 20:02:50.600: E/AndroidRuntime(16322):    at android.app.ActivityThread.handleReceiver(ActivityThread.java:2434)
    10-04 20:02:50.600: E/AndroidRuntime(16322):    ... 10 more
```

The errors of Parse Notifications are in the last entries of the log.
Please Help.

Forever a Newbie.

Answer (score 2):

add the following line to your AndroidManifest.xml file immediately before the closing `</application>` tag:

```
    <meta-data android:name="com.parse.push.notification_icon" 
               android:resource="@drawable/push_icon"/>
```

where `push_icon` is the name of a drawable resource in your package.

Comment: as they specify in the docs, setting the icon is optional https://parse.com/tutorials/android-push-notifications

Answer (score 0):

There is something weird with Parse and push notifications, I've been trying to get it working correctly the way it is supposed to (Parse documentations suggest that it will work out of the box the way you are doing it, and you can customize push notification handeling by extending ParsePushBroadcastReceiver), but ended up doing that to get it working.

Take a look at this answer

https://stackoverflow.com/a/26180181/951448

What you need to do:

- Extend ParsePushBroadcastReceiver class
- Use your custom class to receive the broadcast (in manifest.xml)
- Override onPushOpen to open your activity manually (or handle Open action for the notification the way you want).

Answer (score 0):

Try putting this line in your Application class:

PushService.setDefaultPushCallback(this, YourAttivity.class);

This line should be put after Parse.Initialize() statement.

Try and let me know.