# Open activity when user taps on Parse.com notification

Tags: android, parse-platform, push-notification, android-notifications, android-broadcast

I am using Parse.com for notifications and I want to open MessagesActivy when user taps on incoming notification.

Currently when I tap on notification it opens SplashActivity (start activity), and when I press Back button there is loaded also MessagesActivity.

I am using my own ParseBroadCastReciver to handle onPushOpen, here you can take look at the code.

```
public class MyReciever extends ParsePushBroadcastReceiver {

private static final String TAG = "MyCustomReceiver";
private HashMap<String, String> dataMap;

@Override
protected void onPushOpen(Context context, Intent intent) {
    super.onPushOpen(context, intent);
    if (intent == null) {
        Log.d(TAG, "Receiver intent null");
    } else {
        String action = intent.getAction();
        Log.d(TAG, "got action " + action);
        JSONObject json = null;
        try {
            json = new JSONObject(intent.getExtras().getString("com.parse.Data"));

        } catch (JSONException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        Iterator itr = json.keys();
        dataMap = new HashMap<String, String>();
        while (itr.hasNext()) {
            String key = (String) itr.next();
            Log.d(TAG, "key: "+ key);
            try {
                String value = json.getString(key);
                Log.d(TAG, "value: "+value);
                dataMap.put(key, value);

            } catch (JSONException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }

        if(dataMap.containsKey("from")) {
            Log.d("TAG", "key == from i value == "+dataMap.get("from"));
            Intent msgPushIntenet = new Intent(context, MessagesActivity.class);
            msgPushIntenet.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK );
            msgPushIntenet.putExtra("user_id", dataMap.get("from"));
            //msgPushIntenet.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK | Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP | Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_SINGLE_TOP);
            context.getApplicationContext().startActivity(msgPushIntenet);
            Log.d("TAG", "startujem Messages Activity");
        }


    }
}
```

}

What I can do to open just **MessagesActivity**?

Answer (score 0):

Use this in `onPushOpen` method

```
 Intent msgPushIntenet = new Intent(context, MessagesActivity.class);
            msgPushIntenet.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK );
            msgPushIntenet.putExtra("user_id", dataMap.get("from"));
            context.startActivity(msgPushIntenet);
```

Referring from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26333503/parse-push-no-activity-found-on-opening-push-notification).

Comment: It still first opens SplashActivity (starting Activity). Do you have another idea?