# The method setDefaultPushCallback(Context, Class<? extends Activity>) from the type PushService is deprecated

Tags: parse-platform, push

The whole problem i have been facing is with this line of code

PushService.setDefaultPushCallback(this, MainActivity.class);

on importing PushService the setDefaultPushCallback|() got deprecated. Why is this happening. I receiving the notifications but on tap app is being crashed. Also not receiving when the app isn't running.

Comment: I have the same issue rite now. I am doing some reading on it and I will get back to you.  Hate when people give negative votes without the negative reasoning.

Answer (score 5):

I have found the solution and it is quite simple.
I found the same question 
https://stackoverflow.com/a/26180181/3904085

"
After spending few hours. Found a solution: Implement your receiver and extends ParsePushBroadcastReceiver class.

Receiver.java

```
public class Receiver extends ParsePushBroadcastReceiver {

    @Override
    public void onPushOpen(Context context, Intent intent) {
        Log.e("Push", "Clicked");
        Intent i = new Intent(context, HomeActivity.class);
        i.putExtras(intent.getExtras());
        i.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
        context.startActivity(i);
    }
}
```

Use it in manifest, (Instead of using ParsePushBroadcastReceiver)

Code for project's manifest:

```
<receiver
    android:name="your.package.name.Receiver"
    android:exported="false" >
    <intent-filter>
        <action android:name="com.parse.push.intent.RECEIVE" />
        <action android:name="com.parse.push.intent.DELETE" />
        <action android:name="com.parse.push.intent.OPEN" />
    </intent-filter>
</receiver>
```

"
Credits to @Ahmad Raza

Answer (score 2):

From Parse documentation on onPushOpen():

> Called when the push notification is opened by the user. Sends analytics info back to Parse that the application was opened from this push notification. By default, this will navigate to the Activity returned by ParsePushBroadcastReceiver.**getActivity**(Context, Intent). If the push contains a 'uri' parameter, an Intent is fired to view that URI with the Activity returned by ParsePushBroadcastReceiver.getActivity(android.content.Context, android.content.Intent) in the back stack.

So if you override onPushOpen() like that, no analytics will be sent.

So here is my code:

```
public class Receiver extends ParsePushBroadcastReceiver {

    @Override
    protected Class<? extends Activity> getActivity(Context context, Intent intent) {
        return HomeActivity.class;
    }
}
```

You need to register the receiver like in the above post.

Tested with Parse 1.10.3