# Not receiving Parse Push Notifications In Android

Tags: java, android, parse-platform, push-notification

I am implementing the parse notification in my app, and this is my first time working with push notifications.

I've been following [this](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=HxO3t7ZN4k4) tutorial to get a hang of how parse works!

Then I found out that the `PushService.setDefaultPushCallback(this, MainActivity.class);` has been deprecated and used [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26677029/the-method-setdefaultpushcallbackcontext-class-extends-activity-from-the-t) for guidance.

My code is given below :

AndroidManifest.xml :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.example.pchakraverti.pushnotification" >


    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WAKE_LOCK" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.RECEIVE_BOOT_COMPLETED" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.VIBRATE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.GET_ACCOUNTS" />
    <uses-permission android:name="com.google.android.c2dm.permission.RECEIVE" />

    <!--
      IMPORTANT: Change "com.parse.tutorials.pushnotifications.permission.C2D_MESSAGE" in the lines below
      to match your app's package name + ".permission.C2D_MESSAGE".
    -->
    <permission android:protectionLevel="signature"
        android:name="com.example.pchakraverti.pushnotification.permission.C2D_MESSAGE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="com.example.pchakraverti.pushnotification.permission.C2D_MESSAGE" />


    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >
        <activity
            android:name=".MainActivity"
            android:label="@string/app_name" >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>


        <service android:name="com.parse.PushService" />
        <receiver android:name="com.parse.ParseBroadcastReceiver">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.BOOT_COMPLETED" />
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.USER_PRESENT" />
            </intent-filter>
        </receiver>

        <receiver android:name="com.parse.GcmBroadcastReceiver"
            android:permission="com.google.android.c2dm.permission.SEND">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="com.google.android.c2dm.intent.RECEIVE" />
                <action android:name="com.google.android.c2dm.intent.REGISTRATION" />

                <!--
                  IMPORTANT: Change "com.parse.tutorials.pushnotifications" to match your app's package name.
                -->
                <category android:name="com.example.pchakraverti.pushnotification" />
            </intent-filter>
        </receiver>

        <receiver android:name="com.example.pchakraverti.pushnotification.MyBroadcastReceiver" android:exported="false">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="com.parse.push.intent.RECEIVE" />
                <action android:name="com.parse.push.intent.DELETE" />
                <action android:name="com.parse.push.intent.OPEN" />
            </intent-filter>
        </receiver>

    </application>

</manifest>
```

MyBroadcastReceiver.java :

```
package com.example.pchakraverti.pushnotification;

import android.content.Context;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.util.Log;

import com.parse.ParsePushBroadcastReceiver;

/**
 * Created by PChakraverti on 5/27/2015.
 */
public class MyBroadcastReceiver extends ParsePushBroadcastReceiver {

    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {

        Log.i("TAG", "Push Received");

        /*Intent launchIntent = new Intent(context, MainActivity.class);
        PendingIntent pi = PendingIntent.getActivity(context, 0, launchIntent, 0);

        Notification notification = new NotificationCompat.Builder(context)
                .setContentTitle("Push Notification")
                .setContentText("hello")
                .setContentIntent(pi)
                .setAutoCancel(true)
                .build();

        NotificationManager nm = (NotificationManager)context.getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);
        nm.notify(0, notification);*/
    }
}
```

MainActivity.java :

```
package com.example.pchakraverti.pushnotification;

import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuItem;

import com.parse.Parse;
import com.parse.ParseException;
import com.parse.ParseInstallation;
import com.parse.ParsePush;
import com.parse.SaveCallback;


public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        Parse.initialize(this, "7Wm4v4FP28FHPW06zVBj6Ifcc8QeQObr3LUycs90", "U90b8QH4gLOXGfZLwBSqGqOZSo5GFLiu9sRi4bxW");

        ParsePush.subscribeInBackground("", new SaveCallback() {
            @Override
            public void done(ParseException e) {
                if (e == null) {
                    Log.d("com.parse.push", "successfully subscribed to the broadcast channel.");
                } else {
                    Log.e("com.parse.push", "failed to subscribe for push", e);
                }
            }
        });
    }


    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.menu_main, menu);
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        // Handle action bar item clicks here. The action bar will
        // automatically handle clicks on the Home/Up button, so long
        // as you specify a parent activity in AndroidManifest.xml.
        int id = item.getItemId();

        //noinspection SimplifiableIfStatement
        if (id == R.id.action_settings) {
            return true;
        }

        return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }
}
```

When I am sending push from parse.com, its saying success, but I am not receiving anything on my android device.

*EDIT*

I've updated the code, based on the official tutorial.
But I still have the problem.

Am I still missing something ?

*edit*

logcat:

```
/com.example.pchakraverti.pushnotification I/dalvikvm﹕ Could not find method android.view.ViewGroup.onRtlPropertiesChanged, referenced from method android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar.onRtlPropertiesChanged
05-27 16:41:06.041    1023-1023/com.example.pchakraverti.pushnotification W/dalvikvm﹕ VFY: unable to resolve virtual method 13226: Landroid/view/ViewGroup;.onRtlPropertiesChanged (I)V
05-27 16:41:06.041    1023-1023/com.example.pchakraverti.pushnotification D/dalvikvm﹕ VFY: replacing opcode 0x6f at 0x0007
05-27 16:41:06.041    1023-1023/com.example.pchakraverti.pushnotification I/dalvikvm﹕ Could not find method android.content.res.TypedArray.getChangingConfigurations, referenced from method android.support.v7.internal.widget.TintTypedArray.getChangingConfigurations
05-27 16:41:06.041    1023-1023/com.example.pchakraverti.pushnotification W/dalvikvm﹕ VFY: unable to resolve virtual method 450: Landroid/content/res/TypedArray;.getChangingConfigurations ()I
05-27 16:41:06.041    1023-1023/com.example.pchakraverti.pushnotification D/dalvikvm﹕ VFY: replacing opcode 0x6e at 0x0002
05-27 16:41:06.041    1023-1023/com.example.pchakraverti.pushnotification I/dalvikvm﹕ Could not find method android.content.res.TypedArray.getType, referenced from method android.support.v7.internal.widget.TintTypedArray.getType
05-27 16:41:06.041    1023-1023/com.example.pchakraverti.pushnotification W/dalvikvm﹕ VFY: unable to resolve virtual method 472: Landroid/content/res/TypedArray;.getType (I)I
05-27 16:41:06.041    1023-1023/com.example.pchakraverti.pushnotification D/dalvikvm﹕ VFY: replacing opcode 0x6e at 0x0002
05-27 16:41:06.089    1023-1027/com.example.pchakraverti.pushnotification D/dalvikvm﹕ GC_CONCURRENT freed 199K, 3% free 10928K/11207K, paused 11ms+1ms, total 15ms
05-27 16:41:06.145    1023-1023/com.example.pchakraverti.pushnotification D/libEGL﹕ loaded /system/lib/egl/libEGL_genymotion.so
05-27 16:41:06.145    1023-1023/com.example.pchakraverti.pushnotification D/﹕ HostConnection::get() New Host Connection established 0xb7b8f838, tid 1023
05-27 16:41:06.153    1023-1023/com.example.pchakraverti.pushnotification D/libEGL﹕ loaded /system/lib/egl/libGLESv1_CM_genymotion.so
05-27 16:41:06.153    1023-1023/com.example.pchakraverti.pushnotification D/libEGL﹕ loaded /system/lib/egl/libGLESv2_genymotion.so
05-27 16:41:06.189    1023-1023/com.example.pchakraverti.pushnotification W/EGL_genymotion﹕ eglSurfaceAttrib not implemented
05-27 16:41:06.193    1023-1023/com.example.pchakraverti.pushnotification D/OpenGLRenderer﹕ Enabling debug mode 0
05-27 16:41:06.257    1023-1023/com.example.pchakraverti.pushnotification D/OpenGLRenderer﹕ TextureCache::get: create texture(0xb7c07868): name, size, mSize = 2, 4096, 4096
05-27 16:41:06.629    1023-1027/com.example.pchakraverti.pushnotification D/dalvikvm﹕ GC_CONCURRENT freed 247K, 4% free 11077K/11463K, paused 12ms+0ms, total 14ms
05-27 16:41:07.413    1023-1023/com.example.pchakraverti.pushnotification D/com.parse.push﹕ successfully subscribed to the broadcast channel.
05-27 16:41:08.385    1023-1027/com.example.pchakraverti.pushnotification D/dalvikvm﹕ GC_CONCURRENT freed 352K, 5% free 11163K/11655K, paused 11ms+0ms, total 12ms
05-27 16:41:25.853    1023-1023/com.example.pchakraverti.pushnotification I/TAG﹕ Push Received
05-27 16:44:24.105    1108-1108/com.example.pchakraverti.pushnotification I/dalvikvm﹕ Could not find method android.view.ViewGroup.onRtlPropertiesChanged, referenced from method android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar.onRtlPropertiesChanged
05-27 16:44:24.105    1108-1108/com.example.pchakraverti.pushnotification W/dalvikvm﹕ VFY: unable to resolve virtual method 13226: Landroid/view/ViewGroup;.onRtlPropertiesChanged (I)V
05-27 16:44:24.105    1108-1108/com.example.pchakraverti.pushnotification D/dalvikvm﹕ VFY: replacing opcode 0x6f at 0x0007
05-27 16:44:24.105    1108-1108/com.example.pchakraverti.pushnotification I/dalvikvm﹕ Could not find method android.content.res.TypedArray.getChangingConfigurations, referenced from method android.support.v7.internal.widget.TintTypedArray.getChangingConfigurations
05-27 16:44:24.105    1108-1108/com.example.pchakraverti.pushnotification W/dalvikvm﹕ VFY: unable to resolve virtual method 450: Landroid/content/res/TypedArray;.getChangingConfigurations ()I
05-27 16:44:24.105    1108-1108/com.example.pchakraverti.pushnotification D/dalvikvm﹕ VFY: replacing opcode 0x6e at 0x0002
05-27 16:44:24.105    1108-1108/com.example.pchakraverti.pushnotification I/dalvikvm﹕ Could not find method android.content.res.TypedArray.getType, referenced from method android.support.v7.internal.widget.TintTypedArray.getType
05-27 16:44:24.105    1108-1108/com.example.pchakraverti.pushnotification W/dalvikvm﹕ VFY: unable to resolve virtual method 472: Landroid/content/res/TypedArray;.getType (I)I
05-27 16:44:24.105    1108-1108/com.example.pchakraverti.pushnotification D/dalvikvm﹕ VFY: replacing opcode 0x6e at 0x0002
05-27 16:44:24.185    1108-1111/com.example.pchakraverti.pushnotification D/dalvikvm﹕ GC_CONCURRENT freed 224K, 3% free 10934K/11271K, paused 1ms+0ms, total 2ms
05-27 16:44:24.193    1108-1108/com.example.pchakraverti.pushnotification D/com.parse.push﹕ successfully subscribed to the broadcast channel.
05-27 16:44:24.269    1108-1108/com.example.pchakraverti.pushnotification D/libEGL﹕ loaded /system/lib/egl/libEGL_genymotion.so
05-27 16:44:24.269    1108-1108/com.example.pchakraverti.pushnotification D/﹕ HostConnection::get() New Host Connection established 0xb7c07110, tid 1108
05-27 16:44:24.273    1108-1108/com.example.pchakraverti.pushnotification D/libEGL﹕ loaded /system/lib/egl/libGLESv1_CM_genymotion.so
05-27 16:44:24.273    1108-1108/com.example.pchakraverti.pushnotification D/libEGL﹕ loaded /system/lib/egl/libGLESv2_genymotion.so
05-27 16:44:24.317    1108-1108/com.example.pchakraverti.pushnotification W/EGL_genymotion﹕ eglSurfaceAttrib not implemented
05-27 16:44:24.325    1108-1108/com.example.pchakraverti.pushnotification D/OpenGLRenderer﹕ Enabling debug mode 0
05-27 16:44:24.373    1108-1108/com.example.pchakraverti.pushnotification D/OpenGLRenderer﹕ TextureCache::get: create texture(0xb7c07868): name, size, mSize = 2, 4096, 4096
05-27 16:44:28.565    1108-1108/com.example.pchakraverti.pushnotification D/OpenGLRenderer﹕ TextureCache::flush: target size: 2457
05-27 16:44:28.565    1108-1108/com.example.pchakraverti.pushnotification D/OpenGLRenderer﹕ TextureCache::callback: name, removed size, mSize = 2, 4096, 0
05-27 16:44:52.853    1108-1108/com.example.pchakraverti.pushnotification D/com.parse.push﹕ successfully subscribed to the broadcast channel.
05-27 16:44:52.953    1108-1108/com.example.pchakraverti.pushnotification W/EGL_genymotion﹕ eglSurfaceAttrib not implemented
05-27 16:44:52.969    1108-1108/com.example.pchakraverti.pushnotification D/OpenGLRenderer﹕ TextureCache::get: create texture(0xb7c07868): name, size, mSize = 6, 4096, 4096
05-27 16:54:10.253    1267-1267/com.example.pchakraverti.pushnotification I/dalvikvm﹕ Could not find method android.view.ViewGroup.onRtlPropertiesChanged, referenced from method android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar.onRtlPropertiesChanged
05-27 16:54:10.253    1267-1267/com.example.pchakraverti.pushnotification W/dalvikvm﹕ VFY: unable to resolve virtual method 13227: Landroid/view/ViewGroup;.onRtlPropertiesChanged (I)V
05-27 16:54:10.253    1267-1267/com.example.pchakraverti.pushnotification D/dalvikvm﹕ VFY: replacing opcode 0x6f at 0x0007
05-27 16:54:10.257    1267-1267/com.example.pchakraverti.pushnotification I/dalvikvm﹕ Could not find method android.content.res.TypedArray.getChangingConfigurations, referenced from method android.support.v7.internal.widget.TintTypedArray.getChangingConfigurations
05-27 16:54:10.257    1267-1267/com.example.pchakraverti.pushnotification W/dalvikvm﹕ VFY: unable to resolve virtual method 450: Landroid/content/res/TypedArray;.getChangingConfigurations ()I
05-27 16:54:10.257    1267-1267/com.example.pchakraverti.pushnotification D/dalvikvm﹕ VFY: replacing opcode 0x6e at 0x0002
05-27 16:54:10.257    1267-1267/com.example.pchakraverti.pushnotification I/dalvikvm﹕ Could not find method android.content.res.TypedArray.getType, referenced from method android.support.v7.internal.widget.TintTypedArray.getType
05-27 16:54:10.257    1267-1267/com.example.pchakraverti.pushnotification W/dalvikvm﹕ VFY: unable to resolve virtual method 472: Landroid/content/res/TypedArray;.getType (I)I
05-27 16:54:10.257    1267-1267/com.example.pchakraverti.pushnotification D/dalvikvm﹕ VFY: replacing opcode 0x6e at 0x0002
05-27 16:54:10.309    1267-1270/com.example.pchakraverti.pushnotification D/dalvikvm﹕ GC_CONCURRENT freed 207K, 3% free 10919K/11207K, paused 22ms+0ms, total 23ms
05-27 16:54:10.321    1267-1267/com.example.pchakraverti.pushnotification D/com.parse.push﹕ successfully subscribed to the broadcast channel.
05-27 16:54:10.353    1267-1267/com.example.pchakraverti.pushnotification D/libEGL﹕ loaded /system/lib/egl/libEGL_genymotion.so
05-27 16:54:10.353    1267-1267/com.example.pchakraverti.pushnotification D/﹕ HostConnection::get() New Host Connection established 0xb7c59dd8, tid 1267
05-27 16:54:10.361    1267-1267/com.example.pchakraverti.pushnotification D/libEGL﹕ loaded /system/lib/egl/libGLESv1_CM_genymotion.so
05-27 16:54:10.361    1267-1267/com.example.pchakraverti.pushnotification D/libEGL﹕ loaded /system/lib/egl/libGLESv2_genymotion.so
05-27 16:54:10.397    1267-1267/com.example.pchakraverti.pushnotification W/EGL_genymotion﹕ eglSurfaceAttrib not implemented
05-27 16:54:10.405    1267-1267/com.example.pchakraverti.pushnotification D/OpenGLRenderer﹕ Enabling debug mode 0
05-27 16:54:10.469    1267-1267/com.example.pchakraverti.pushnotification D/OpenGLRenderer﹕ TextureCache::get: create texture(0xb7c07868): name, size, mSize = 2, 4096, 4096
```

It can be seen that there is one "Push Received" logged in the logcat extract.

But after that, I am not receiving anything again!

What is going on ?

*Update*

```
05-27 13:47:20.888    1500-1500/com.example.pchakraverti.pushnotification E/AndroidRuntime﹕ FATAL EXCEPTION: main
    Process: com.example.pchakraverti.pushnotification, PID: 1500
    java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start receiver com.parse.ParseBroadcastReceiver: java.lang.RuntimeException: applicationContext is null. You must call Parse.initialize(Context) before using the Parse library.
            at android.app.ActivityThread.handleReceiver(ActivityThread.java:2586)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.access$1700(ActivityThread.java:144)
            at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1355)
            at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
            at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:135)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5221)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:899)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:694)
     Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: applicationContext is null. You must call Parse.initialize(Context) before using the Parse library.
            at com.parse.Parse.checkContext(Parse.java:448)
            at com.parse.Parse.getApplicationContext(Parse.java:267)
            at com.parse.ManifestInfo.getContext(ManifestInfo.java:324)
            at com.parse.ManifestInfo.getPackageManager(ManifestInfo.java:328)
            at com.parse.ManifestInfo.getPackageInfo(ManifestInfo.java:358)
            at com.parse.ManifestInfo.deviceSupportsGcm(ManifestInfo.java:446)
            at com.parse.ManifestInfo.getPushType(ManifestInfo.java:212)
            at com.parse.PushService.startServiceIfRequired(PushService.java:222)
            at com.parse.ParseBroadcastReceiver.onReceive(ParseBroadcastReceiver.java:19)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.handleReceiver(ActivityThread.java:2579)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.access$1700(ActivityThread.java:144)
            at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1355)
            at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
            at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:135)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5221)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:899)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:694)
```

Comment: I ran into a similar issue with Parse. It was working on some devices while on others it wasn't. After weeks of frustration, I switched to Amazon's AWS Push Notification and it has been working great so far.

Comment: Thing is registration in Amazon's AWS needs credit card info, which I do not have. Some solution to this problem will be helpful!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Generally, I recommend the [official tutorial](https://www.parse.com/tutorials/android-push-notifications).

1. Your `com.parse.ParseBroadcastReceiver` uses wrong action names and should read:

   ```
   <receiver android:name="com.parse.ParseBroadcastReceiver">
       <intent-filter>
           <action android:name="android.intent.action.BOOT_COMPLETED"/>
           <action android:name="android.intent.action.USER_PRESENT"/>
       </intent-filter>
   </receiver>
   ```
2. You're lacking this receiver (code from the tutorial linked above):

   ```
   <receiver android:name="com.parse.GcmBroadcastReceiver"
       android:permission="com.google.android.c2dm.permission.SEND">
     <intent-filter>
       <action android:name="com.google.android.c2dm.intent.RECEIVE" />
       <action android:name="com.google.android.c2dm.intent.REGISTRATION" />

       <!--
         IMPORTANT: Change "com.parse.tutorials.pushnotifications" to match your app's package name.
       -->
       <category android:name="com.parse.tutorials.pushnotifications" />
     </intent-filter>
   </receiver>
   ```
3. You have to enable push notifications by subscribing to a channel, e.g., via:

   ```
   ParsePush.subscribeInBackground("", new SaveCallback() {
       @Override
       public void done(ParseException e) {}
   });
   ```

Comment: I've updated the code based on your post and the official tutorial. But I am still having the problem. Am I missing something again ?

Comment: I've added logcat, please check that.

Comment: Are you sending the push notification again?

Comment: Yes. I sent another 4 notifications and none of them reached my device

Comment: Why are you overriding onReceive instead of onPushReceive?

Comment: Now I am getting this : Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: applicationContext is null. You must call Parse.initialize(Context) before using the Parse library. I read this up in the internet but nothing seems to solve this

Comment: Tutorial item 4: initialize Parse in your *Application* class' `onCreate` method.

Answer (score 0):

Also a common reason could be using server API key form GCM console.
Whilst API key from Firebase project should be used instead.