# Android - Parse push notification crashes on open

Tags: java, android, parse-platform, push-notification

I have set up parse push notifications and I had my app crash when I tried to open it, now I found a work around my making a new java class and overriding `onPushOpen` like this:

```
public class Receiver extends ParsePushBroadcastReceiver {

    @Override
    public void onPushOpen(Context context, Intent intent) {
        Intent i = new Intent(context, MainActivity.class);
        i.putExtras(intent.getExtras());
        i.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
        context.startActivity(i);
    }
}
```

But in order to still receive push notifications I still need this depreciated method in my MyApplication.java class `PushService.setDefaultPushCallback(this, MainActivity.class);`

How could I get rid of this depreciated method I have looked at this question where I got some help but it did not answer this part about the depreciated method. [Exception when opening Parse push notification](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26154855/exception-when-opening-parse-push-notification).

I was thinking that maybe this method could be over ridden but Im not sure if it acutely handles recvieving the push or more handles the push after it has been received?

```
@Override
    public void onPushReceive(final Context c, Intent i) {
        // Handle the received push
    }
```

Thanks for the help in advance.

Comment: https://www.parse.com/docs/push_guide#top/Android. What parse jar version are you using?

Comment: @Raghunandan I am using 1.7.1 the newest version, and I have followed the quick step guide and looked over the docs, and if you look at the method PushService.setDefaultPushCallback it says it depreciated.

Comment: that is not needed. You have custom broadcast receiver. All you need to do is show notification there.

Comment: @Raghunandan but when I remove that line I can no longer receive notifications. So what are you saying I should replace it with?

Answer (score 0):

You are subclassing `ParsePushBroadcastReceiver`.

Then in manifest

```
    <receiver
        android:name=".Receiver " // your broadcastreceiver
        android:exported="false" >
        <intent-filter>
            // youtr actions
        </intent-filter>
    </receiver>
```

In BroadCastReceiver

```
public class Receiver extends ParseBroadcastReceiver {

@Override
public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {

    super.onReceive(context, intent);

        extras = intent.getExtras();
        if(intent.hasExtra("com.parse.Data")) 
        {
            try
            {
             json = new JSONObject(intent.getExtras().getString("com.parse.Data"));
             int notificationtype = json.getInt("notificationtype"); // this is send on the sender side
             switch(notificationtype)
             {
              case 1:

                    // show your custom notification. Refer android notification guide 

                break;
                case 2:
                //rest of the code
```

Note : If either "alert" or "title" are specified in the push, then a Notification is constructed using `getNotification`. So no alert and title on the sender side.

Read Managing Push Lifecycle @

https://www.parse.com/docs/push_guide#receiving/Android

Reference

https://www.parse.com/questions/how-suppress-push-notification-from-being-displayed

Comment: on the `new JSONObject` line I am getting compile error `Unhanded exception org.JSON.JSONException` and on the  `extras = intent.getExtras();` complie error `cannot resolve symbol extras`

Comment: @iqueqiorio you need to declare the extras as `Bundle extras`. Also it depends on how you send the data on the sender side. DO you use json. That is for you to figure out.

Comment: I am just sending text strings through cloud code, so no I am just sending plain text. So do I not need the JSON part?

Comment: @iqueqiorio read the documentation. If you just want push notification you do need not subclass `ParsePushBroadcastReceiver`. Make sure you have the alert and title and you will have the notification displayed. In case you need to custom notfication subclass `ParsePushBroadcastReceiver` and then handle the notification part yourself. Again read the docs

Comment: I have read and re-read the docs, but when I removed the `setDefaultPushCallback` depreciated method, I can't receive the push notification?

Comment: @iqueqiorio https://parse.com/docs/android/api/deprecated-list.html. It says `com.parse.PushService.setDefaultPushCallback(Context, Class)`
          Replaced by `ParsePushBroadcastReceiver`.

Comment: okay I see that but that I still don't know what should replace that line? Because if its not there the push doesn't go through.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/66083/discussion-between-raghunandan-and-iqueqiorio).