# Android - Can not Receive Push from Parse.com

Tags: java, android, parse-platform, push-notification

I have parse notifications set up for my android app using Parse 1.7.1 sdk version.

But in the new android this method with parse says to call is depreciated.

```
PushService.setDefaultPushCallback(this, MainActivity.class);
```

But when it is removed the notification is sent from parse.com as I can see on the website but it does not arrive to the phone?

How can this be changed so that the push will arrive? Without using the depreciated method?

Thanks for the help in advance.

Comment: Your question seems duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27262255/android-parse-push-notification-crashes-on-open/27262791?noredirect=1#comment42998567_27262791.

Answer (score 1):

Try extending ParsePushBroadcastReceiver class and and use its

- OnPushRecieve (to do something before notification is shown in status bar)
- OnPushOpen (to  do some action when user open's push for example open an activity)
- getNotification and
- onPushDismiss methods

  And in manifest file replace

```html
<receiver android:name="com.parse.ParsePushBroadcastReceiver" android:exported="false">
  <intent-filter>
    <action android:name="com.parse.push.intent.RECEIVE" />
    <action android:name="com.parse.push.intent.DELETE" />
    <action android:name="com.parse.push.intent.OPEN" />
  </intent-filter>
</receiver>
```

with this :

```html
 <receiver
            android:name="com.example.parse.Notifications.NotificationsReciever"
            android:exported="false" >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="com.parse.push.intent.RECEIVE" />
                <action android:name="com.parse.push.intent.DELETE" />
                <action android:name="com.parse.push.intent.OPEN" />
            </intent-filter>
        </receiver>
```

And if you want to open an activity **onPushOpen**, here is a sample:

```js
@Override
 protected void onPushOpen(Context context, Intent intent) {
  // TODO Auto-generated method stub
  Intent i = new Intent(context, PushNotificationHandler.class);
  i.putExtras(intent.getExtras());
  i.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
  context.startActivity(i);
 }
```

Here is a sample class that extends ParsePushBroadcastReciever class

```js
public class NotificationsReciever extends ParsePushBroadcastReceiver {

 @Override
 protected Class<? extends Activity> getActivity(Context arg0, Intent arg1) {
  // TODO Auto-generated method stub

  return ParseStarterProjectActivity.class;
 }

 @Override
 protected Notification getNotification(Context context, Intent intent) {
  // TODO Auto-generated method stub
  return super.getNotification(context, intent);
 }

 @Override
 protected void onPushDismiss(Context context, Intent intent) {
  // TODO Auto-generated method stub
  super.onPushDismiss(context, intent);
 }

 @Override
 protected void onPushOpen(Context context, Intent intent) {
  // TODO Auto-generated method stub
  Intent i = new Intent(context, PushNotificationHandler.class);
  i.putExtras(intent.getExtras());
  i.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
  context.startActivity(i);
 }

 @Override
 protected void onPushReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
 //here You can handle push before appearing into status e.g if you want to stop it.
  super.onPushReceive(context, intent);
  
 }

}
```

Comment: com.example.parse.Notifications.NotificationsReciever where can I get this class? Or am I supposed to make one?

Comment: Bro you have to make this class I am adding a sample in my answer.

Comment: I have a receiver class made

Comment: Good now add this class to manifest as described in answer.Hope this works.