# Android Studio: App does not receive push notifications from parse.com

Tags: android, android-studio, parse-platform, push-notification

I know that this question has been asked many times but i am still unable to get push notifications from parse.com

The push Notifications are being successfully sent from parse.com but my app does not receive them.

Most people have their problem resolved using this: [I can't receive push notifications in app from Parse](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27367362/i-cant-receive-push-notifications-in-app-from-parse) bt that doesnt work for me.

I also tried [Android - Can not Receive Push from Parse.com](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27263602/android-can-not-receive-push-from-parse-com).

Some people suggest changing names of packages, i did that and even made a new app but didnt help.

**Note**: i have imported parse-1.9.1.jar and bolts-android-1.2.0.jar

Here is my MainActivity

```
package com.example.user.parsetest;

import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v7.app.ActionBarActivity;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuItem;
import com.parse.Parse;
public class MainActivity extends ActionBarActivity {

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    Parse.initialize(this, "********", "********");

}
}
```

I tried adding custom PushReceiver as suggested in many answers

```
package com.example.user.parsetest;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.app.Notification;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.Intent;
import com.parse.ParsePushBroadcastReceiver;

public class Receiver extends ParsePushBroadcastReceiver {

@Override
protected Notification getNotification(Context context, Intent intent) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    return super.getNotification(context, intent);
}

@Override
public void onPushOpen(Context context, Intent intent) {
    Intent i = new Intent(context, MainActivity.class);
    i.putExtras(intent.getExtras());
    i.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
    context.startActivity(i);
}
@Override
protected void onPushReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
    //here You can handle push before appearing into status e.g if you want to stop it.
    super.onPushReceive(context, intent);

}
}
```

And the AndroidManifest.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
```

```
<application
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >
    <activity
        android:name=".MainActivity"
        android:label="@string/app_name" >
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
    <service android:name="com.parse.PushService" />
    <receiver android:name="com.parse.ParseBroadcastReceiver">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.BOOT_COMPLETED" />
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.USER_PRESENT" />
        </intent-filter>
    </receiver>
    <receiver android:name="com.example.user.parsetest.Receiver"
        android:exported="false">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="com.parse.push.intent.RECEIVE" />
            <action android:name="com.parse.push.intent.DELETE" />
            <action android:name="com.parse.push.intent.OPEN" />
        </intent-filter>
    </receiver>
    <receiver android:name="com.parse.GcmBroadcastReceiver"
        android:permission="com.google.android.c2dm.permission.SEND">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="com.google.android.c2dm.intent.RECEIVE" />
            <action android:name="com.google.android.c2dm.intent.REGISTRATION" />

            <!--
              IMPORTANT: Change "com.parse.starter" to match your app's package name.
            -->
            <category android:name="com.example.user.parsetest" />
        </intent-filter>
    </receiver>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WAKE_LOCK" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.VIBRATE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.RECEIVE_BOOT_COMPLETED" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.GET_ACCOUNTS" />
    <uses-permission android:name="com.google.android.c2dm.permission.RECEIVE" />
    <meta-data android:name="com.parse.push.notification_icon"
        android:resource="@drawable/ic_launcher"/>

    <!--
      IMPORTANT: Change "com.parse.starter.permission.C2D_MESSAGE" in the lines below
      to match your app's package name + ".permission.C2D_MESSAGE".
    -->
    <permission android:protectionLevel="signature"
        android:name="com.example.user.parsetest.permission.C2D_MESSAGE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="com.example.user.parsetest.permission.C2D_MESSAGE" />
</application>
```

Unable to figure out the problem. pleaseeee help.

Comment: Are you getting any error?

Comment: Firstly check on the Parse console if notification is sent properly. 
Secondly remove the default receiver's entry from manifest i.e  <receiver android:name="com.parse.ParseBroadcastReceiver">
......
    </receiver>

Comment: Just a wild speculation..but try using Parse-1.8.2 jar and bolts-android-1.1.4.jar? This combination (previous versions) seems to be working for me

Comment: @Napolean.. yes the Parse console says that the notification has been sent.. but there are 0 receivers.. Removing the entry from the manifest didnt help either

Comment: @droidx.. how can i download the parse1.8.2 jar file?? coz the official SDK has version 1.9.1

Comment: @SwapnaLekshmanan use this : https://www.dropbox.com/sh/kcdw7nb7f71xgio/AABDkPPr4XT9VZPtIT5ZpBjKa?dl=0

Comment: @SwapnaLekshmanan pratikdasa@gmail.com drop me an email here, let we try to sort it out, if u dnt mind.

Comment: @SwapnaLekshmanan just curious..were you able to resolve this?

Comment: @SwapnaLekshmanan how u resolved this issue i m getting same ?

Comment: Not yet..i thought to give it in later versions of app. will surely post the answer if i manage to get it done. @Erum  do share your answer if you are able to do the same

Comment: make sure your installation id for current user still exist

Answer (score 0):

In your Application class just after the line for Parse.initialize(appkey,clientkey); just add the following line and it should work.

```
// Current installation object
ParseInstallation parseInstallation = ParseInstallation.getCurrentInstallation();

// Save the updated installation object
parseInstallation.saveInBackground(new SaveCallback() {
    @Override
    public void done(ParseException e) {
        MyLog.e(MainApplication.class.getSimpleName(), "Installation object saved "+((e!=null)?"failed":"successfully"));
    }
 });
```

Comment: Still the same.. push sent.. not received :(

Comment: I did added this project few days ago. Can you try running this sample project https://github.com/Keshava11/parsecheck  And in ParseCheckApplication  class replace the keys with you.

Comment: @Napolean..parecheck project does not run in eclipse.i.e it crashes just after the launch and in Android Studio, there is an error of cannot find plugin com.android.application

Comment: do you have any existing project in Android Studio. In that project do File-> Import module -> this module

Comment: @Napolean  i m also getting same issue ?

Answer (score 0):

Try downloading this project: https://www.dropbox.com/s/fpp22fi2o7c8vai/PushParse.zip?dl=0

It contains the 1.4.3 lib jar file. It's outdated but it's working.

I did, with a bit of tweaking, managed to update it to the latest library (1.9.2).

Watch out for errors that appear in your logcat. I got this: [error setting up push notification using parse.com and android studio](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26355187/error-setting-up-push-notification-using-parse-com-and-android-studio)

If fixed by making sure my android manifest is very clean and organized. Follow the structure.

Here's my code for the updated parse library:

```
public class ParsePushNotification extends Application {

    public ParsePushNotification() {
    }


    public void onCreate(){
        super.onCreate();

        Log.d("!!!", "This was called. Parse");
        Parse.initialize(this, "paste your app id here", "paste your client id her");
//        PushService.setDefaultPushCallback(this, LoginActivity.class);
//        ParseInstallation.getCurrentInstallation().saveInBackground();
        ParsePush.subscribeInBackground("", new SaveCallback() {
            @Override
            public void done(ParseException e) {
                if (e == null) {
                    Log.d("com.parse.push", "successfully subscribed to the broadcast channel.");
                } else {
                    Log.e("com.parse.push", "failed to subscribe for push", e);
                }
            }
        });
    }
}
```

That class should be used here in your manifest:

```
<application
      android:name="com.example.app.ParsePushNotification"
```

Here's my receiver class:

```
public class Receiver extends ParsePushBroadcastReceiver {
    @Override
    public void onPushOpen(Context context, Intent intent) {
        Intent i = new Intent(context, LoginActivity.class);
        i.putExtras(intent.getExtras());
        i.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
        context.startActivity(i);
    }
}
```

Here's my manifest:

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.RECEIVE_BOOT_COMPLETED" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.VIBRATE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WAKE_LOCK" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.GET_ACCOUNTS" />
    <uses-permission android:name="com.google.android.c2dm.permission.RECEIVE" />
    <permission android:name="com.example.app.permission.C2D_MESSAGE"
        android:protectionLevel="signature" />
    <uses-permission android:name="com.example.app.permission.C2D_MESSAGE" />

<application
        android:name="com.example.app.ParsePushNotification"
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:theme="@style/Theme.NoTitle">

    <meta-data
        android:name="com.parse.push.notification_icon"
        android:resource="@drawable/ic_launcher" />

    <activity
        android:name=".LoginActivity"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:screenOrientation="portrait" >
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>

    <service android:name="com.parse.PushService" />
    <receiver android:name="com.parse.ParseBroadcastReceiver">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.BOOT_COMPLETED" />
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.USER_PRESENT" />
        </intent-filter>
    </receiver>
    <receiver android:name="com.parse.GcmBroadcastReceiver"
        android:permission="com.google.android.c2dm.permission.SEND">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="com.google.android.c2dm.intent.RECEIVE" />
            <action android:name="com.google.android.c2dm.intent.REGISTRATION" />
            <category android:name="com.example.app" />
        </intent-filter>
    </receiver>
    <receiver android:name="com.example.app.Receiver"
        android:exported="false">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="com.parse.push.intent.RECEIVE" />
            <action android:name="com.parse.push.intent.DELETE" />
            <action android:name="com.parse.push.intent.OPEN" />
        </intent-filter>
    </receiver>
</application>
```

Good luck!

Comment: how do you get onPushOpen() to work? Whenever I sent push through console I am unable to see the notificationto pen.

Comment: what do you mean "through console"? Please try to download the sample project to test your push notifications.

Comment: Perhaps when you registered your app, it saved the object id in the installation class. Then you deleted it, but you didn't uninstall the app? Because it happened to me a couple of times my app can't receive the push because it's no longer registered.

Try uninstalling the app then installing it again see if creates a new row in the installation class in Parse Core.