# Error ~ parse.com push notification android?

Tags: java, android, parse-platform, push-notification, push

I just make my first steps in android programming and I wanna try to realise parse.com push notification. I use 1.8.0 version. When i tested i had next errors:

1) Error:(20, 68) error: cannot access Task class file for bolts.Task not found.

2) setDefaultPushCallback is deprecated.

Here below you can see code that i used. What i missed and what i need to change?! Maybe someone have good example?

**ParseReceiver.java**

```
public class ParseReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver {
    private final String TAG = "Parse Notification";
    private String msg = "";
    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context ctx, Intent intent) {
        Log.i(TAG, "PUSH RECEIVED!!!");

        try {
            String action = intent.getAction();
            String channel = intent.getExtras().getString("com.parse.Channel");
            JSONObject json = new JSONObject(intent.getExtras().getString("com.parse.Data"));

            Log.d(TAG, "got action " + action + " on channel " + channel + " with:");
            Iterator itr = json.keys();
            while (itr.hasNext()) {
                String key = (String) itr.next();
                Log.d(TAG, "..." + key + " => " + json.getString(key));
                if(key.equals("string")){
                    msg = json.getString(key);
                }
            }
        } catch (JSONException e) {
            Log.d(TAG, "JSONException: " + e.getMessage());
        }


        Bitmap icon = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(ctx.getResources(),
                R.drawable.happy);

        Intent launchActivity = new Intent(ctx, MainActivity.class);
        PendingIntent pi = PendingIntent.getActivity(ctx, 0, launchActivity, 0);

        Notification notification = new NotificationCompat.Builder(ctx)
                .setContentTitle("PUSH RECEIVED")
                .setContentText(msg)
                .setSmallIcon(R.drawable.happy)
                .setLargeIcon(icon)
                .setContentIntent(pi)
                .setAutoCancel(true)
                .build();

        NotificationManager notification_manager = (NotificationManager)ctx.getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);
        notification_manager.notify(0, notification);
    }
}
```

**ParseApplication.java**

```
public class ParseApplication extends Application {
    @Override
    public void onCreate() {
        super.onCreate();
        Parse.initialize(this, Keys.applicationId, Keys.clientKey);
        PushService.setDefaultPushCallback(this, MainActivity.class);
        ParseInstallation.getCurrentInstallation().saveInBackground();
    }

}
```

**Keys.java**

```
public class Keys {
    protected static final String applicationId = "";
    protected static final String clientKey = "";
}
```

**In Manifect file i used next code**

```
<!-- Permissions required for parse.com notifications -->
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.RECEIVE_BOOT_COMPLETED" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.VIBRATE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WAKE_LOCK"/>
<!-- END Parse permissions -->

<!-- My custom receiver -->
<receiver android:name=".ParseReceiver" >
<intent-filter>
<action android:name="com.makemyandroidapp.parsenotificationexample.RECEIVE_PUSH" />
</intent-filter>
</receiver>
<!-- END my custom receiver -->

<!-- Required for Parse.com notifications -->
<service android:name="com.parse.PushService" />
<receiver android:name="com.parse.ParseBroadcastReceiver" >
<intent-filter>
       <action android:name="android.intent.action.BOOT_COMPLETED" />
       <action android:name="android.intent.action.USER_PRESENT" />
</intent-filter>
</receiver>
<!-- END Parse.com requirements -->
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1) You should check your Eclipse project's libs folder. Possibly you are missing the latest bolts jar file. This is part and parcel of the zip that contains the parse lib files.

2) Unfortunately, the official tutorials are somewhat misleading because they are not fully updated with the latest changes of the API. Actually this was necessary until Parse version 1.6, if I am not mistaken.
 
Now, as you can see in your custom receiver's code, you set the activity that is going to open when clicking the notification by setting a pending intent. Check this note of [deprecation](https://parse.com/docs/android/api/index.html?com/parse/PushService.html). 
The current implementation, using the new [ParsePushBroadcastReceiver](https://parse.com/docs/android/api/index.html?com/parse/ParsePushBroadcastReceiver.html), is more flexible than ever! So instead of extending the BroadcastReceiver, extend this one. Be sure to read the documentation about this. It is very helpful.

Also:
a) In your manifest replace the portion of the "My custom receiver" with the following

```
<receiver android:name=".ParseReceiver" android:exported="false">
    <intent-filter>
        <action android:name="com.parse.push.intent.RECEIVE" />
         <action android:name="com.parse.push.intent.OPEN" />
         <action android:name="com.parse.push.intent.DELETE" />
    </intent-filter>
</receiver>
```

b) Change this

```
<receiver android:name="com.parse.ParseBroadcastReceiver" >
```

to your own custom receiver

```
<receiver android:name="com.makemyandroidapp.parsenotificationexample.ParseReceiver">
```

c) In your manifest make sure to use the ParseApplication class you have created as the  name attribute:

```
<application
    android:name=".ParseApplication"
    ....
    ....
 />
```

I hope the above will help you continue with your project.

Comment: @LuckyLuky Hello! Sure, in documentations i noticed that they advice to replace 
setDefaultPushCallback to ParsePushBroadcastReceiver. In one topic here i found some informations, but dont understand how use it correct. Can u check it http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26154855/exception-when-opening-parse-push-notification/26180181#26180181. Is it mean that i need to use their Receiver.java instead of ParseReceiver.java?! As a matter of fact now for me its big confusion cause i dont understant what to do with PasreApplication.java and in what place put the keys now. Can you explain me pls.

Comment: Your own receiver class is just fine. Just change your class declaration to this `public class ParseReceiver extends ParsePushBroadcastReceiver` and replace onReceive() declaration with this `public void onPushOpen(Context ctx, Intent intent) ` (although onReceive() works just fine as it is). Concerning the ParseApplication.java do you got the app key and the client key from parse? If so, apply them on Keys.java and you are OK. [Here](http://pastebin.com/QwXRbi0D) I quote the whole AndroidManifest.xml for your convenience to check the differences from your code.

Comment: I made as you said. I used public class ParseReceiver extends ParsePushBroadcastReceiver instead of my old one, then replaced OnReceive to onPush method and added to open MainActivity after Push open. I noticed duplication of .ParseReceiver in Manifect in your sourse. It it ok?! And last one what i want to ask is this line in ParseApplication.java i have problems with them
        ParseInstallation.getCurrentInstallation().saveInBackground(); What i need to do?! Error is the same as before:cannot access Task class file for bolts.Task not found.

Comment: The Manifest works as it is but check [this](http://pastebin.com/2XyKuzV7) for a more visually optimized version of it. All you have to care about is the min,target sdk versions and the package name (on top of manifest) to point to your own. In order to overcome the Task class problem go [here](https://parse.com/docs/downloads), download the SDK(v1.8.0), unzip it and copy bolts-android-1.1.4.jar,bolts-android-1.1.4.jar.properties,Parse-1.8.0.jar and Parse-1.8.0.jar.properties to your libs folder in Eclipse project.If there isn't any create one on top level of the project. Then clean and build.

Comment: Thank you @LuckyLuke now there are no errors and parse.com service see my device but when i send message there is no notification in my emulatore device. Whats the reason of that? Have you got any ideas about that? By the way Happy New Year! =)

Comment: But in real device i have push, so its little bit strange! Thank you again!

Comment: Happy New Year Nurzhan! Actually the GCM is the component that is missing on the emulator. I suspect you are using the stock emulator, so try using a "Google APIs" emulator image before opening it. This may do the trick. One last remark is to revert back to onReceive() instead of onPushOpen() because that way you will avoid duplicate push messages to show on tray. Please, mark my answer as accepted or any of the comments you feel that helped the most, if you feel there is one. Thank you. :)